Binomial mean and variance, and linear transformation
A presses on a button in a machine and then the machine chooses two numbers from the set {1,2,3,4} with replacement. If the multiplication of the two numbers is even, he gets 5 dollars. Otherwise he gets nothing. To participate, he pay 2 dollars, regardless of either winning or losing.
What is the expected value and variance of the profit after 100 such games ?
What I did was:
$P(A)=\frac{12}{16}=0.75$
and then X is the number of winnings, so:
$X\sim Bin(100,0.75)$
and therefore:
$E(X)=100\cdot 0.75=75$
and
$V(X)=100\cdot 0.75\cdot 0.25=18.75$
and then if Y is the profit:
$E(Y)=5\cdot 75-200=175$
$V(Y)=25\cdot 18.75=46875$
I have tried several AI tools. They all think I am wrong. I can't see why. What do you think ?

I think its correct. As a general rule, I would not suggest to rely on AI tools to verify your solutions or learn the correct methods to solve math problems.

The probability of $A$ (which I assume was the probability that for two numbers $X$ and $Y$ independently and uniformly chosen in ${1,2,3,4}$ have an even product) seems correct. The law of $X$ is also the good one, and the expectation and variances of $X$ are correct. Now, $Y$ can be written as $5X-200$, so that $E[Y]$ is correct, and $V(Y)=468.75$ (the point was missing). Why would you ask AI ?
